# How to resolve ConfigurationError error 'Unknown directive' in Plone?

Tags: plone

I created new plone site after that I created new product using the following command

```
 ../bin/zopeskel plone_basic dummy.work
```

I created browser folder under ../dummy.work/src/dummy/work .then I configured the browser folder in configure.zcml file  as like below.

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone"
    xmlns:zcml="http://namespaces.zope.org/zcml"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="dummy.work">

    <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />
    <plone:static
        directory="browser"
        type="work"
        name="dummy.work"
        />

    <genericsetup:registerProfile
        name="default"
        title="dummy.work"
        directory="profiles/default"
        description="Installs the dummy.work package"
        provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
        />
    <include package=".browser" />
</configure>
```

when i try to create an instance i am getting the error like

```
ConfigurationError: ('Unknown directive', u'http://namespaces.plone.org/plone', u'static')
```

can any one help me to solve this problem

Comment: Which version of Plone are you using?

Comment: i have installed plone 4.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the `plone:static` directive you must include the `meta.zcml`.

It's documented in the package documentation at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.resource/

```
You must do <include package="plone.resource" file="meta.zcml"/> before you can use the plone:static directive.
```

So: add the line `<include package="plone.resource" file="meta.zcml"/>` before the usage of `plone:static`.